# Why is openapi-generator renaming ReadOnly to VarReadOnly and how can I make it stop doing that?

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-cli

We use openapi-generator, which  has recently been updated to run version 7 and require JRE class version 55 (instead of previously 52)

Now when it generates our API client code, all of our usages of properties named `ReadOnly` have been renamed `VarReadOnly`. This breaks a lot of things for us.

For reference, this is the command I send to the CLI:

```
openapi-generator-cli.cmd generate 
    --reserved-words-mappings readonly=readonly 
    -g csharp 
    -i http://localhost:5111/swagger/v1/swagger.json 
    --global-property skipFormModel=false -t '.\Templates\out'       
    --additional properties=targetFramework='net6.0',
        packageName=OurApi.Api.Client,useDateTimeOffset=true`
```

Note that I have specified `--reserved-words-mappings readonly=readonly`, and it still doesn't work

and this is a sample of the OpenApi doc:

```
  "BankAPIModel": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "readOnly": { //<-- this will be output as VarReadOnly
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "bankInfo": {
        "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Bank"
      },
      "pendingchangeid": {
        "type": "integer",
        "format": "int32"
      }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
  },
```

And this is the resultant output

[image]

What can I do to enforce openapi-generator to treat this parameter/property as it's originally named?

Comment: do not include pictures of code, include the code as code. That being said, it looks like you are using C#, where readonly is a reserved keyword. The openapi-generators dodge reserved keywords of the target language by changing them (I have not used it for C#, but I know it does it for other languages)

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the suggestion to not include pictures of the code. The text of the code is irrelevant in this context and the image includes more information than simply a copy/paste of the text.

Comment: you have a point, this may be the one time where an image of code is the right call, it would have been difficult to do the highlighting otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C#-generator of openapi-generator had an intentional breaking change in version 7.0.0 to handle property names which collide with reserved keywords of the language (and readonly is a keyword in C#).
I do not see any documented way around this feature.

release notes:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/releases/tag/v7.0.0

I believe this is the correct PR:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/13681

Note that `readOnly` and `readonly` are considered equivalent by the generator when it comes to checking if a property-name is a reserved keyword:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/13681/commits/f91bd4974a9a8384e6870a24f0b97f0621817760